# Order of functions by rate of growth (from slowest to fastest) as $x$ gets very large

Tags: asymptotics

For the following functions, I ordered them from slowest to fastest as follows:

1st. $100^x$

2nd. $5^x$

3rd. $x^{100}$

4th. $x^6$

5th. $x^5$

6th. $x^5\log_2x$

7th. $\log_2x$

8th. $5$

I got it wrong and received no feedback. Any clues?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out numbers $5$ and $6$.

Comment: I should have paid attention! Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Everything else looks good ?

Comment: What if you differentiate all the functions with respect to $x$? This will give you the exact rate of change.

Comment: Also, when you say from **slowest to fastest**, then $5$ (appearing at number 8) should appear above as it is the **slowest** (not growing at all)!

Comment: I see that the order is wrong, should be the opposite with 5th and 6th swapped?